# Clean URL assistance php/.htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm looking to make some cleaner urls so that it basically, the web address looks nicer.

currently my url looks like this ..
`...co.uk/article.php?sport=football&id=23`.. & title for the post could be.. erm .."this is the title"

i have been looking around the web and all over youtube trying to find a video to help as i hardly take any info in when i read stuff, so videos seems more productive for me. What i would like is my url to read something like...

`...co.uk/sport/football/this-is-the-title` .. and if it was another topic something like...
`...co.uk/sport/tennis/this-is-another-title` ...something nice and clean and tells people exactly what they're looking at. Also, i would like to have it so when its on pages, them pages dont have to have there extension added on so you dont have to put `.php` or `.html` on the end of the address as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep id also in the pretty URL like the URL structure of Stackoverflow here. So instead of: `/sport/football/this-is-the-title` have it like:

```
/sport/football/23/this-is-the-title
```

Once that is settled let's now look into establishing mod_rewrite code to achieve it.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^sport/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?sport=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: firstly i want to say thanks, you didnt need to do that code, just pointing me in the dierection of somethingthat would of help would of been enough for me! So thanks, i think im starting to understand after spending all night trying to read more and more things on rewrite, i just have one question which is, after going to the new 'clean'/'fancy' url, there seems to be not a single bit of styling on the page, everything just appears in its most simplest of forms, how come this is the case?

Comment: You're not the only one who deals with broken css, js links after switching to pretty URLs. Reason is use of relative links in your pages to retrieve css, js, image files. If you can change them to absolute paths like starting from `/` or `http://` then it will start working.