# Decoding the facebook & google+ url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, url

I have been wondering how facebook directs users based on the url. For example:-`https://www.facebook.com/fadia.ankit‎` . Normally this means that they save a folder with name fadia.ankit and there is a index.php in that folder. But on `https://www.facebook.com/fadia.ankit‎/index.php` a 404 error is shown. So if anyone can direct me probably how are they using the url.

Another example in this is `https://www.facebook.com/messages/12231277329` .

I think that there is some kind of `javascript` behind this. I am just curious to know(many a rookie like me are). Please Help if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook are not creating directories for each users. They are using HTACCESS url rewriting. See www.9lessons.info/2009/01/htaccess-tutorials.html

Comment: You should search for `url rewriting`.

Comment: If it were a folder, it would end in a `/`, and JavaScript has nothing to do with any of this. Facebook has written *hundreds of millions* of lines of custom server software code. They certainly don't need to resort to stupid "folders" to implement a username URL. I'm sure the server is programmed to just look up the name directly and then generate a page with that user's info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just use an url rewriting routine, such as htaccess: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

In reality `https://www.facebook.com/fadia.ankit` is probably something like `https://www.facebook.com?user=fadia.ankit`, using normal `$_GET` variables.

But using .htaccess rewriting, they manage to rewrite the url and make a cleaner one out of it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234252/clean-url-assistance-php-htaccess) on how to generate clean URLs.